# Sales Region in Sale Module Openerp 7

Tags: odoo

Is there a default provision to track sales region in sales order so that region wise sales can be analyzed in future. I know that we can simply add a field to manage that. But i would like to know if it's already present in openerp as it's one of the most essential feature for sale module. Please feel free to edit the post for better clarity in question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no such provision in openerp in sales, which filters it based on region. However as you said, you could add a field and thereby filter it in reporting based on the region.